# Give Sidekiq queue a maximum size limit

Tags: sidekiq

Recently one queue for reporting exceptions got overflowed by jobs, causing Redis to use too much memory and finally crash.

I want to give some Sidekiq queue a maximum job option. Jobs should be dropped if the queue is full. Is there an option or gem to provide this functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing out there today that I know of that provides **real** queue backpressure.  Some ideas, hope this helps:

Use Inspeqtor to monitor your Redis instance:

https://github.com/mperham/inspeqtor/wiki/Daemon-Specific-Metrics#redis

Monitor your queue backlog:

https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Monitoring#monitoring-queue-backlog